# JHipster - 404 when running executable jar

Tags: jhipster

Given JHipster is using springboot,  I created a new empty JHipster project and attempted to run the resulting executable jar (java -jar jhipster-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar).  I am receiving a 404 return code when attempting to access the site http://localhost:8080.

If I do gradle bootRun it works.

Any thoughts?

Gradle OSX Yosemite

Comment: Having the same issue, I just hope @julien-dubois can give us a hint...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in a maven project when I package the jar with the development profil. Make sure that you use the production profil:

```
gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage
```

and then run the jar with the development profil

```
java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

or with the production profil

```
java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Comment: In this shows running the war file, not the jar.  The war file seems to run but the jar file appears to start up correctly but when you hit the site it returns 404